# Centering an image within a slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have set my images so that they overflow the div that contains them which is exactly what I want, but I want the images to be centered vertically on all browsers at the moment them just overflow at the bottom. I have tried to use transform to do this with no luck. Any ideas? Sorry but I can't attach the full code as it is too long, so I will just post a small part so that I can add my codepen link. Please go to my codepen demo. https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/OgZGvJ

```html
<div id="head">
  <p>Head</p>
</div>

<div class="carousel">
  <div><img src="http://fyberproperty.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/stairs_one1200-1-1024x512.png" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://fyberproperty.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/stairs_two1200-1024x512.png" /></div>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: try using css [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give a try at the flex display properties:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.carousel{
  display:flex!important;/* overrides previous values or set via js */
  align-items:center;/* that's where centering happens and overflows on both sides */
}
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MoXZve

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
    }); 
  });
```

```css
html,
body,
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#head {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

p {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex!important;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel div img {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Slick Slider */

.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slick-list:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-list.dragging {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.slick-track:after {
  clear: both;
}

.slick-loading .slick-track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide {
  float: right;
}

.slick-slide img {
  display: block;
}

.slick-slide.slick-loading img {
  display: none;
}

.slick-slide.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}

.slick-loading .slick-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
  display: none;
}

@charset 'UTF-8';

/* Slider */

.slick-loading .slick-list {
  background: #fff url('./ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}


/* Icons */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'slick';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('./fonts/slick.eot');
  src: url('./fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('./fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('./fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}


/* Arrows */

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus {
  color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.slick-prev:hover:before,
.slick-prev:focus:before,
.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
.slick-next.slick-disabled:before {
  opacity: .25;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  font-family: 'slick';
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: .75;
  color: white;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: -25px;
}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev {
  right: -25px;
  left: auto;
}

.slick-prev:before {
  content: '←';
}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before {
  content: '→';
}

.slick-next {
  right: -25px;
}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-next {
  right: auto;
  left: -25px;
}

.slick-next:before {
  content: '→';
}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before {
  content: '←';
}


/* Dots */

.slick-dotted.slick-slider {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-dots li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-dots li button {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-dots li button:before {
  font-family: 'slick';
  font-size: 6px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '•';
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .25;
  color: black;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  opacity: .75;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<div id="head">
  <p>Head</p>
</div>

<div class="carousel">
  <div><img src="http://fyberproperty.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/stairs_one1200-1-1024x512.png" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://fyberproperty.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/stairs_two1200-1024x512.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect I tried using flex before but I must of been putting it on the wrong element. Will this work in all browsers? Thanks

Comment: @Reece, any browsers that supports flex should, if not, it will behave just as when you wrote the question. :)  See http://caniuse.com/#search=flex